# Is it possible to see some error output in Zeppelin paragraphs?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a Zeppelin installation and am using the Spark interpreter. However, if I have a syntax or runtime error, I cannot find any details except the "Error" word.

For example, I have this code:

[image: Example 1]

And I only see the "ERROR" word in the top-right corner.

In my own computer, scala would instead print something like:

```
$ scala example.sc
./example.sc:1: error: recursive value a needs type
val a = this is an error
             ^
.example.sc:1: error: not found: value an
val a = this is an error
                ^
two errors found
```

I'm using version 0.7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set `zeppelin.spark.printREPLOutput` to `true` in the `Interpreter` tab.

The downfall of this is that it will show everything that REPL shows.

Comment: Do you know if this config setting works for Python output too? The docs at https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#configuration suggests this setting only affects Scala.