# Zeppelin does not display stack trace

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I installed Zeppelin 0.8.0 on Windows 10. When I write in a notebook with spark interpreter, correct code works fine, outputs are displayed, but stack trace is not  displayed in case of error. It's like in is written in white, but actually lines between ^ are empty.

[image: The empty stack trace]

**EDIT:** REPL output seems to be enabled (with interpreter option `zeppelin.spark.printREPLOutput`) since I got an error output. But it's as if stacktrace was emptied just before printing, causing only `^` pointers to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. I am having the same issue. I am using Zeppelin 0.8.2, and have set "zeppelin.spark.printREPLOutput" to "TRUE". Most of the time paragraph doesn't show any error logs. Did you find any solution or work around?

Comment: No sorry I did not succeed... If I remember well I used a Linux VM to make it work correctly instead. I'm not sure Zeppelin is quite ready for Windows yet

Comment: I am also using Linux but still receive this error. I switched from open-jdk-11 to oracle java 1.8 and from zeppelin 0.8.3 to zeppelin 0.7.3. So far its working good. I am able to see the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Set `zeppelin.spark.printREPLOutput`
property to 'true' in Spark interpreter

Comment: This option is set by default according to [the official documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/spark.html#configuration). I tried it anyway, but that does not change anything.

Comment: This answer actually works when no error output is displayed at all. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073664/is-it-possible-to-see-some-error-output-in-zeppelin-paragraphs). But as you can see, there is no empty lines with `^` displayed in this case.